# How can I return an empty parameterised class Box?

Tags: java, generics

I am learning generics in Java.
How can I return an empty parameterised class Box in the method getBox?  Thanks for helping.

```
public static <T> class Box<T> {
    private  T object;
    
    public static <T>Box<T> getBox() {   
        return new Box<T>();        
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `Box` as `class Box<T> {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<T>` before the keyword `class`, but keep the `<T>` after the class name.

There is a difference in declaring the type parameter for classes and declaring the type parameter for methods.  For the generic method `getBox`, you declared the type parameter, correctly, before the return type, even if most people put a space between the type declaration and the return type.  But for a generic class, the `<T>` *after* the class name declares type parameter `T`; any `<T>` before the class name is a syntax error.